# Cloud Functions Deployment Issue (.Net 6)

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-functions, .net-6.0

This is the first time I'm working on Google Cloud Functions. I've created a http trigger cloud function using .Net6 framework and trying to deploy it using gcloud Cli. The deployment was failing, and I know why but don't know how to solve it.

I've couple of cs-projects, Cloud Functions project (CFP), Application Services project (ASP) and DBRepositories project (DBP). CFP has a reference of ASP which then has a reference of DBP. I've initiated the deployment from the directory of where Function1.cs(CFP) located. The deployment was unable to locate the other two projects rereferred to CFP.

Project reference visualization:

`CloudFunctions.csproj <- ApplicationServices.csproj <- DBRepositories.csproj`

I even initiated the deployment from the directory where solution file is located but failed with error "Too many projects found."

Cli command:
gcloud functions deploy demo-function --entry-point HelloFunction.Function1 --runtime dotnet6 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --gen2 --region us-central1

I'm stuck here, any help greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Are you deploying the function in the correct directory together with the file(s)? Based on this documentation on [deploying the function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-dotnet#deploying_the_function), `To deploy the function with an HTTP trigger, run the following command in the helloworld directory.` I've followed this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-dotnet) and encountered no issues.

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you for the reply. This documentation has a specification of Dependency Injection using Function Startup class, but not about Cloud Function project with other Projects as Dependencies.

After lot of googling found this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-dotnet/blob/main/docs/examples.md#multiprojectfunction-and-multiprojectdependency). Now I'm getting another issue when I try to set dependency project as suggested in this document.

Comment: Following is cli command as per the suggestion in the documentation 

'gcloud functions deploy testfunction --entry-point CloudHttpFunction.Function --runtime dotnet6 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --gen2 --region us-central1 --set-build-env-vars=GOOGLE_BUILDABLE=CloudFunctionDependency'

The issue I'm getting now is, 
If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the '/layers/google.dotnet.publish/publish/bin/CloudFunctionDependency.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework. runtimeconfig.json is created after a successful publish, but in this case isn't.